# Data Lake Analytics call from .Net SDK (user not authorize)

Tags: azure, authorization, azure-data-lake

Currently I'm trying call my U-SQL Jobs from data lake analytics in my web application. To do this I'm using official .net sdk. I'm authorizing with azure by another web app that is placed in azure active directory and have access to data lake files (which works perfect in my app too) and have read rights to data lake analytics resource group. I'm just tring with some options from internet (turn of firewall on both services, check if i have data lake store az data source in data lake analytics) but it is not work :/ So maybe is there another work around for my problem ? Or i should use another way to authorize me in data lake analytics sdk and perform my U-SQL jobs ?

Here is my error message in visual studio:

Additional information: The user does not have the permission to perform this **operation.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I very recently ran into something similar. For me, it was due some permissions settings:
1) Check if the App user has access to the system\job folder and all its children. Also do the same for the catalog folder in case you are using an internal u-sql database
Or:
2) Also, the app might need to be owner of the data lake store.

Let me know if this helps...

Comment: Thanks for response, what actually helps is Add User Wizard and set up my web active directory app as Data Lake Analytics Developer and set up permissions to all data lake file.

Comment: @dawcza94 Thanks for the feedback. Yes, I also forgot that option. That Wizard basically does the same thing. Please don't forget to set the question as answered